# Completely rename the default context of commit status from github-plugin

Tags: git, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

While using the Github plugin to trigger build automatically when a new PR coming up or new commit (for multiple branch pipeline job). I  want to change the commit status context so each job will be separated with the others.

I acquire this by using the built-in "setBuildStatus" function in their document (https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Github+Plugin)
But instead of replacing the default context, it just adds another context. So if I have 3 job runs for the PR, I'll have 4 checks.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWydP.png)

How can I completely remove the: `continuous-integration/jenkins/pr-merge`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Disable GitHub Multibranch Status](https://plugins.jenkins.io/disable-github-multibranch-status/) Jenkins plugin.
After installation you will be able to add "Disable GitHub Notifications" behavior to your job configuration.
[image: Jenkins configuration screenshot]